# ember {{action}} doesn't work

Tags: ember.js

I want button to call removeAlbum function in controller. But it does nothing. When i click the button nothing happens and there are no errors... What should i do to fix that?!

This is my template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="albums">
  {{#if App.albumsController.total}}
    <div><h1>Количество альбомов: {{App.albumsController.total}}</h1></div>
    {{#each content in App.albumsController}}
      <div class='album'>
        <div class='image'>
          <a {{action showAlbum content href=true}}>
            <img {{bindAttr src="content.avatarUrl"}}>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class='info'>
          <h2>
            <a {{action showAlbum content href=true}}>
              {{content.title}}
            </a>
          </h2>
          <div>{{content.description}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class='actions'>
          <div>
            <button {{action removeAlbum content target="App.albumsController"}}>Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='clear'></div>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <div><h1>Loading</h1></div>
  {{/if}}  
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
App.albumsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
  content: [],
  total: null,
  loadAlbums: function(){
    this.set('content', []);
    this.set('total', null);
    var self = this;
    $.post(App.connection.url, {method: 'albums.getAll', params: {user_id: App.connection.userId}}, function(response){
      self.set('total', response.albums.total);
      response.albums.album.forEach(function(item){
        var buf = App.AlbumInList.create({
          id: item.id,
          title: item.title,
          description: item.description,
          avatarUrl: item.thumbnail_video.thumbnails.thumbnail[1]._content        
        });
        self.pushObject(buf);
      });
    });
  },
  removeAlbum: function(x){
    console.log('remove it');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm in my ember applications, the controllers can't be found right on App. I find them just in the router: App.router.albumsController . Maybe try this? You could also use just controller instead of its fully qualified path in your App.

Comment: In my router there is only application controller

Comment: Why do you create the Controller yourself? Why don't you use Ember.ArrayController.extend({...}) and let the framework create the Controllers by calling App.initialize() ?

Comment: Would it be possible to put your code in a jsfiddle ? here is a starting point, with Ember.js required resources: http://jsfiddle.net/6p6XJ/

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your target to controller instead of App.albumsController. Should solve the problem.

```
<button {{action removeAlbum content target="controller"}}>Delete</button>
```